# Like to play a random sequence of tones when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a total newb at this stuff, but I would like to have a random set of 4 tones play in succession when Button 5 is clicked.....

I have a basic understanding about arrays, Math.random, setInterval... but can't wrap my slow brain around how to make something as simple as this work.
Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

All I have is the code to make the sounds trigger individually.....

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $(".button_1").click(function () {
    $('#sound-1').get(0).play();
    });

    $(".button_2").click(function () {
    $('#sound-2').get(0).play();
    });

    $(".button_3").click(function () {
    $('#sound-3').get(0).play();
    });

    $(".button_4").click(function () {
    $('#sound-4').get(0).play();
    });

    $(".button_5").click(function () {
    $("????").get(0).play();
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding script for each button isn't the best way to work. Since there's a visible pattern for buttons 1 through 4, you can program using that pattern instead.

Comment: According to the information you provided, the only possible answer is replace `????` with `sound-5`. Please include the a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to play a single random sound. You can use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1` for a number from 1 to 4 , and do `"#sound-"+randNum`:

```
$(".button_5").click(function () {
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; 
    $("#sound-"+ranNum).get(0).play();
});
```

To play a number of random songs in succession you can use `setInterval()`, and keep track of how many times it ran, then `clearInterval()` when you are done:

```
$(".button_5").click(function () {
    var plays = 4; // Play 4 sounds, each a second apart.
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;  
        $("#sound-"+ranNum).get(0).play();
        plays--;
        if(plays < 1) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Just note that it can repeat a sound, if you don't want repeats you need to keep track of what sounds where played.

Finally, you may want to make sure that you can't click the button again until the sounds played are finished. A basic way to do this is `disable` the button until the interval is over:

```
$("#button_5").click(function () {
    var plays = 4;
    var self = this;
    $(self).prop( "disabled", true );
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1  
        $("#sound-"+ranNum).get(0).play();
        plays--;
        if(plays < 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $(self).prop( "disabled", false );
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**Here is a fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uL0o9vwb/1/). Note in the example I'm just doing `console.log("#sound-"+ranNum)` instead to show what would play.

Comment: Thanks, like I said I'm a total newb, but this gets me moving in the right direction......

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function that plays the sound, and then call that four times.

```
function playSound(number){
    $('#sound-' + number).get(0).play();
}

$(".button_5").click(function () {
    var tones = 1;
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        if(tones>=4) clearInterval(t);
        playSound(Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1));
        tones++;
    }, 1000);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/roanrj6e/

Comment: Thanks.....this was kind of what I thinking in my head, but I'm definitely too green with JS to execute it.